# ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.delete deletes but also throws a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, shopify, shopify-api

I'm using the ShopifyAPI Ruby gem. As part of the gem I can delete the InventoryLevel of a product at a specific location.

This works well:

```
  ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.delete(
    inventory_item_id: "correct_id",
    location_id: "and_another_correct_id"
  )
```

The issue is, is that after the level is deleted the API then throws this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass)
```

This happens every time and I have no idea why.

This happening to anyone else? Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a crazy comment. Why would you ever even want to delete an InventoryLevel? It is not actually a thing you delete. What are really trying to do? 

In my mind, you would more likely want to just set inventory to zero at that location, hence freeing you up from wanting to worry about it anymore? 

Or is this more of a philosophical thing you're aiming at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error message tells you that something is calling `nil.empty?` when you trigger that method, so it's just a matter of finding out *where* that's happening.

What version of the gem are you using? [ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel#delete](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-ruby/blob/be3697d3e3d88ad33048284d96aa858153d525ea/lib/shopify_api/rest/resources/2023_04/inventory_level.rb#L56) just sends an API request, so an error like that is going to be somewhere in the gem's logic for how it handles the response to that request. Skimming the repo, the request method it's calling is probably `ShopifyAPI::Clients::HttpClient#request`. The `#delete` method is sending a [DELETE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) request to their API, which should return a 204 No Content response. The HTTP Client file shows that they are calling `.empty?` and there is handling for a nil response body, but if you look at the file's version history you can see that this was added in a commit less than a year ago tagged [v13.4.0](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-ruby/commit/4e74ccab25dad7f58346f0eefd7bfd8016b654bf). You're likely using a version of the gem older than that bugfix and just need to update it.